# Allowing access with .htaccess (by address AND auth)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following, but its not working correctly.

I run this server locally, but have now configured for external access. I want it to work such that if you're not within my internal network, you must authenticate.

Authentication works, however cannot get httpd to accept this code so something must be wrong. Just can't figure out which!

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all    
Satisfy Any

Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 192.168

AuthUserFile "C:/Program Files/wamp/htpasswd.txt"
AuthName "Piss off :-)" 
AuthType Basic 

Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the `Order`:

```
Order Allow,Deny
```

Comment: Did that, wampserver still won't load. (It remains orange, if you're familiar with wamp).

Nothing in the apache error log

Comment: Do you have a space after the `,` between `Allow,Deny`? Because, for reasons that are entirely beyond me, you can't do that :(

Comment: I did, and that fixed it. Wampserver now loads. However, when I access the site from an external address (ie. not 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.*.*) it allows me access, when I'm wanting it to prompt for authentication.

Comment: Scrap that. I had an existing session open ;-). Many thanks for help David.